# My python script stops... no error, just stops

Tags: python, banner

I am running a script that iterates through a text file. On each line on the text file there is an ip adress. The script grabs the banner, then writes the ip + banner on another file.
The problem is, it just stops around 500 lines, more or less, with no error. 
Another weird thing is if i run it with python3 it does what i said above. If i run it with python it iterates through those 500 lines, then starts at the beggining. I noticed this when i saw repetitions in my output file. Anyway here is the code, maybe you guys can tell me what im doing wrong:

```
import os
import subprocess
import concurrent.futures
#import time, random
import threading
import multiprocessing


with open("ipuri666.txt") as f:



    def multiprocessing_func(): 
        try:
            line2 = line.rstrip('\r\n')
            a = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-I", line2, "--connect-timeout", "1", "--max-time", "1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            b = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "Server"], stdin=a.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            #a.stdout.close()
            out, err = b.communicate()
            g = open("IP_BANNER2","a")
            print( "out: {0}".format(out))
            g.write(line2 + " " + "out: {0}\n".format(out))
            print("err: {0}".format(err))

        except IOError:
            print("Connection timed out")


    if __name__ == '__main__': 
        #starttime = time.time()
        processes = []
    for line in f:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_func, args=()) 
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation of your code block - the import statements were outside of it, however some parts of it doesn't look right. They were not OK also in your original formatting and may be the cause of the problem. Can you check and make the indentation as it is in your real code.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. Its the same indentation as in original

Comment: What errorcode does it exit with?

Comment: no error, just stops

Comment: Not error, errorcode. After it quits, run `echo @?` on Linux or `echo %errorlevel%` on windows.

Comment: i may sound funny/stupid but if I write echo@? i get exactly echo@? in bash :))

Answer (score 0):

If your use case allows I would recommend just rewriting this as a shell script, there is no need to use Python. (This would likely solve your issue indirectly.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray -t ips < ipuri666.txt
for ip in ${ips[@]}; do
    output=$(curl -I "$ip" --connect-timeout 1 --max-time 1 | grep "Server")
    echo "$ip $output" >> fisier.txt
done
```

The script is slightly simpler than what you are trying to do, for instance I do not capture the error. This should be pretty close to what you are trying to accomplish. I will update again if needed.

Comment: I have a file with IP's on each line. i run the script and it banner grabs every ip from that file. on each iteration, my script writes to a new file the ip adress plus the response from banner grab, greping only the server part. So at the end i have a file with IP adress + Server version running on that IP

Comment: thank you, ill try and assemble the code, even though I dont know bash i think i can make it

Comment: My man, why is this bash script not working? Its working until I write ">" ... if I write > fisier.txt it does not write anthing to the file 

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray -t ips < ipuri666.txt
for ip in ${ips[@]}; do
    # curl command
    curl -I "$ip" --max-time 2  | grep Server > fisier.txt
    # grep command
    # write output to file
    done`

i don't know how to format the code in comment; PS: here is the pastebin with code https://pastebin.com/UZP6R0p4

Comment: In bash, `>` will overwrite the file each time. You want to use `>>` to append. You may want to simply print your output on each loop first without writing to a file for debugging. I updated the script above a little while ago, check those edits and they should help as well.

Comment: I checked the script but it gives me ./script.sh: line 6: =: command not found, thats the line starting with output=

Comment: I solved it somehow, now this is my code: `

#!/usr/bin/env bash
readarray -t ips < ipuri666.txt
for ip in ${ips[@]}; do
  
    curl -I "$ip" --max-time 2  | grep Server >> fisier.txt && echo $ip >> fisier.txt
  
    done` ... Now when i run it the server version and IP are on different lines, is there a way to put them in each line?

Comment: Sorry its a little late for me! I had some extra spacing around the `=`.

Comment: I edited the code block above to reflect your last comment! Hopefully that takes care of it.

Comment: one more question... the script is very slow, i want to run  the for loop in paralel... unfortunately if i put "&" at the end of command i get jumbled results. Is any way i can make the loop iterate faster? I have a file with more than a million IP adresses and it will take forever without some king of threading

Comment: Ah, I don’t know of a way to make that faster in bash- you can certainly split the file into pieces and rewrite to different new files and combine them. In this case Python may be a better choice, although your program will not be incredibly fast either way.